# Test if an account has write access to a path

Tags: powershell, acl

Is there a reliable way to test if an account (user or computer AD account) has access to a folder using PowerShell, that doesn't rely on a third party binary?

- `AccessChk` does exactly what I need.

  - I could put a PS wrapper function around it, but I'm hoping there's a solution that doesn't require bundled binaries.
  - It also reports on a folder's contents permissions rather than the permissions on the given directory.  That's easy enough to work around, but isn't ideal.
- I've seen solutions that use `Get-ACL` then compare the `IdentityReference` value... but

  - that only works if the account has explicit permissions; not if it's via group membership
  - you also have to account for inherited permissions, `allow` vs `deny`, as well as ensuring the file system rights matching the required access.
- These cover the NTFS permissions, but don't take into account the Share permissions; though both impact the access.
- A common method is to try performing the operation you're testing the rights for and say that if it works all's OK; but that requires having the account's credentials.

---

## Example Wrapper for AccessChk

```
Function Test-FileAccess {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$Account = "$($env:USERDOMAIN)\$($env:USERNAME)"
        ,
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$Path = '.'
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$ItemName # required since AccessChk lists permissions on contents, not on the root path
        ,
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$PathToAccessChk = 'AccessChk.exe' # if AccessChk is in $env:Path all's good; if not provide the full path to the exe
        ,
        [Parameter()]
        [switch]$Read
        ,
        [Parameter()]
        [switch]$Write
    )
    Process {
        $result = $false
        $accessTest = '*' + ('R' | ?{$Read.IsPresent}) + ('W' | ?{$Write.IsPresent}) + '*'
        $pth = (Resolve-Path $Path).Path 
        $itemPth = Join-Path -Path $pth -ChildPath $ItemName
        $rgx = '^(?<permission>\S*)\s*{0}\s*$' -f [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Escape($itemPth)
        foreach($line in (. $PathToAccessChk -accepteula -q $Account $Path) -split '[\r\n]+\s*') {
            if ($line -match $rgx) {
                $result = ($matches['permission'] -like $accessTest)
                break;
            }
        }
        $result
    }
}
```

Comment: What... is your question? :) You've already determined that `accesschk.exe` does the job and you have a working wrapper

Comment: They are asking if a native Powershell method exists for this, without relying on an executable.

Comment: Thank-you both - as @BendertheGreatest says, I'm hoping for something that doesn't rely on a third party exe.  I've updated the question to make that clearer.

Comment: Take a look at: [link](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1982988-powershell-command-to-check-if-user-has-permissions-to-a-folder)

Comment: Thanks @PaulvdElst; however that seems to use the `IdentityReference` approach, which is fine for explicit access, but doesn't work if the user is granted access due to being a member of a group, or because their SIDHistory contains the SID of an account with access, etc.